# How to check velocity is using mirrored data in meteor with mocha

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, meteor-velocity

I am using velocity + mocha for testing my meteor app. On client side when I run test case like below, it is passing.

```
describe("categories server", function(){

  it("should return categories", function(done){

    setTimeout(done,1500);
    chai.assert(Cats.find({}).count() > 0);
    this.timeout(1500);
  });
```

But on Client side I'm getting blank collection for the similar test.And in mocha iframe all fields dependent on db are empty. Please any help is much appriciated. I'm new in testing.

Comment: What is 'the similar test' you refer to? Since tests are done in the mirror, which starts off with nothing in it,  I would expect 'Cats' to be empty. In fact normally for tests of this kind you start off filling the mirror db with records, and then run the test. I don't think you need the timeouts.

Comment: Here is the point where I'm getting confused, if we expect 'Cats' to be empty then why above test case is passing in server side but failing on client side. And I also referred to mocha example from https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity-examples

Comment: And if I don't use timeouts then "timeout of 2000ms exceeded " is coming...

Comment: Do you subscribe to any data in the Cats collection? You can remove the done parameter and setTimeout lines because nothing asynchronous happens in the test. You can use `meteor mongo` and the switch to the mirror database with `use mocha` to validate what your database contains.

Comment: So on "meteor mongo" and "use  mocha " I found that database has no collections except default ones. And where do I have to subscribe to Cats collection in test file also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Execute `meteor mongo` to get into the MongoDB shell of your app.
2. Execute `use mocha` in the MongoDB shell to switch to the database that the Mocha mirror uses.
3. Validate the contents of your database with something like: `db.cats.find().pretty()`.

Comment: only these collections are present:            meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration, 
meteor_oauth_pendingCredentials,
system.indexes,
users

Comment: Make sure that the file where you declare your collection is also executed on the server. It should not be in a client folder.

Comment: I am declairing every collection in models folder with schema. And using subscribe and publish methods.